# How to pull an email address from one field into another

Tags: email, workflow, formula, field-update

I'm wanting to insert the Account 'Email' value in to another field in a Workflow action but am having some trouble getting the formula right.

This is what I Have so far..

Workflow rule =  `**Account: Email not equal to null**'

Immediate Action; field update: '**new email field**' equals formula: '**PersonEmail**'

I've also tried **TEXT(PesonEmail)** in the formula but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, it seems that you enabled Person Account in your organization. If that's the case, then you will have to check the `IsPersonAccount` field rather then checking the `Email` field.

So your workflow's rule criteria should be `IsPersonAccount` equal to `true` and not `Email` not equal to `null`

As your current rule criteria is `Email` not equal to `null`, which will always be false, hence your workflow is not firing.

Change your workflow to

**Workflow rule = `Account: IsPersonAccount equal to true`**

**Immediate Action: field update: `new email field` equals formula: `PersonEmail`**

You can find further help on [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000220212&type=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) Salesforce knowledge article.

Comment: Thanks for reply! You're correct in that Person Account is enabled, however there is  PersonEmail option isn't available

Comment: Updated the answer, you can also refer  the Salesforce help link for further help.

Answer (score 0):

There are below possibilities that you need to check:

1. Is your workflow activated?
2. Please refer below image for reference. In your case object should be Account and Field to Update should be Account field.

[image: Please refer below image for reference. In your case object should be Account and Field to Update should be Account field.]

3. If above screenshot does not resolve your issue then please paste your code.

Comment: Hi Anurag, yes configured as you descirbed above. Code I am using is: TEXT (PersonEmail), but I have also tried just entering Personemail in the formula box also